# How do i deploy a Fragment in a Fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I am trying to use the wizard built by Roman Nurik (https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager).

I am deploying this in a fragment and i am getting this error.
One of the classes calls on OnAttach to an activity, however, Its been called by a fragment.

Please help

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: Activity must implement PageFragmentCallbacks
at sfam.ui.com.MultipleChoiceFragment.onAttach(MultipleChoiceFragment.java:100)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:788)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:731)
at android.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:1012)
at android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompatICSMR1.setUserVisibleHint(FragmentCompatICSMR1.java:23)
at android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat$ICSMR1FragmentCompatImpl.setUserVisibleHint(FragmentCompat.java:48)
at android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat.setUserVisibleHint(FragmentCompat.java:76)
at android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:156)
at sfam.com.SFASurveyForm$MyPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(SFASurveyForm.java:461)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1071)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:762)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2163)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1091)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2505)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
```

Method)

Answer (score 2):

It says `Activity must implement PageFragmentCallbacks`? Thus .. make your Activity implement PageFragmentCallbacks.

If you have access to the WizardPager code, you can change `onAttatch()` to use `getParentFragment()` instead of `getActivity()`, thereby letting your parent fragment handle the role of implementing `PageFragmentCallbacks`